# R - generate dynamic number of columns and substring column values

Tags: r, spotfire

looking for some help with data manipulation in R. I have data in the following format;

```
ID  L1  L2  L3
1   BBCBCACCBCB CBCBBBB BEBBBAAB
2   BBCBCCCCBCB CBCCCBC BBAACCCB
3   BBCBCACCBCB CBCBBBB BEBBBAAB
4   BBCBCACCBCB CBCBBBB BEBBBAAB
5   BBCBACBCCCB BBCCCBC BBCBAAAAB
6   BBCBBCCBBCB BBCBCEB BBBBCAACB
7   BBCBBCCBBCB BBCBCEB BBBBCAACB
8           
9   BBCBCACCBCB CBCBBBB BEBBBAAB
10  BBCBBCCBBCB BBCBCEB BBBBCAACB
11  BBCBBCCBBCB BBCBCEB BBBBCAACB
```

The values in each column will be strings of varying length. I want an R function that for each column above, will

1) generate a dynamic number of columns based on the maximum length of any string in the column e.g. L1 max length = 11, therefore 11 new columns each labelled L1_1:L1_11

2) then split the strings into triplets, e.g.

```
ID  L1  L2  L3  L1_1    L1_2    L1_3    L1_4    L1_5    L1_6    L1_7    L1_8    L1_9
1   BBCBCACCBCB CBCBBBB BEBBBAAB    BBC BCB CBC BCA CAC ACC CCB CBC BCB
```

3) perform a calculation on this triplet i.e. (number of 'a' * 1) + (number of 'b' * 3) + (number of 'c'*7) in the triplet.

4) return the value of this calculation in the new column.

I have found that the code suggested does exactly what I need when run for columns L1, L2 but does not work for L3. The error I receive is 'Error in as.data.frame.matrix(passed.args[[i]], stringsAsFactors = st : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'

Any ideas?
Thanks very much.

EDIT

dput(df):

```
structure(list(ID = 1:11, L1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BBCBACBCCCB","BBCBBCCBBCB","BBCBCACCBCB", "BBCBCCCCBCB"), class = "factor"), L2 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("","BBCBCEB","BBCCCBC", "CBCBBBB", "CBCCCBC"), class = "factor"), L3 = structure(c(5L,2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BBAACCCB", "BBBBCAACB", "BBCBAAAAB", "BEBBBAAB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "L1", "L2", "L3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-11L))
```

structure(list(ID = 1:11, L1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BBCBACBCCCB","BBCBBCCBBCB","BBCBCACCBCB", "BBCBCCCCBCB"), class = "factor"), L2 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("","BBCBCEB","BBCCCBC", "CBCBBBB", "CBCCCBC"), class = "factor"), L3 = structure(c(5L,2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BBAACCCB", "BBBBCAACB", "BBCBAAAAB", "BEBBBAAB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "L1", "L2", "L3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-11L))

Comment: Hi @Ash_23S, if the answer below worked for you, please consider accepting it (check mark to the left). It lets the community know it worked and that the issue is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#DATA
df = structure(list(ID = 1:4, L1 = c("abbbcc", "aabacd", "abbda", 
"bbad")), .Names = c("ID", "L1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

#Go through the strings and split into subgroups of 3 characters.
#Put the substrings in a list
temp = lapply(df$L1, function(x) sapply(3:nchar(x), function(i) substr(x, i-2, i)))

#Obtain the length of the subgroup with the most triplets
temp_l = max(lengths(temp))

#Subset the subgroups from 1 to temp_l so that remianing values are NA
cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(a)
    a[1:temp_l]))), nm = paste0("L1_",1:temp_l)))
#  ID     L1 L1_1 L1_2 L1_3 L1_4
#1  1 abbbcc  abb  bbb  bbc  bcc
#2  2 aabacd  aab  aba  bac  acd
#3  3  abbda  abb  bbd  bda <NA>
#4  4   bbad  bba  bad <NA> <NA>
```

If you want calculation based on triplets, run the following before doing the `cbind` step

```
temp_L1 = lapply(df$L1, function(x) sapply(3:nchar(x), function(i) substr(x, i-2, i)))
temp_L1_length = max(lengths(temp_L1))
temp_L1 = lapply(temp_L1, function(x)
             sapply(x, function(y){
                     num_a = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "a", text = y))
                     num_a = sum(num_a > 0)  #length of positive match
                     num_b = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "b", text = y))
                     num_b = sum(num_b > 0)
                     num_c = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "c", text = y))
                     num_c = sum(num_c > 0)
                     num_a * 1 + num_b * 3 + num_c * 7
                 })
         )
temp_L1 = setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp_L1, function(a)
              a[1:temp_L1_length]))), nm = paste0("L1_",1:temp_L1_length))

#REPEAT FOR L2, L3, ...

cbind(df, temp_L1)   #Run cbind(df, temp_L1, temp_L2, ...)
#  ID     L1 L1_1 L1_2 L1_3 L1_4
#1  1 abbbcc    7    9   13   17
#2  2 aabacd    5    5   11    8
#3  3  abbda    7    6    4   NA
#4  4   bbad    7    4   NA   NA
```

**UPDATE**

You could create a function and use it like shown below

```
#FUNCTION
foo = function(data, column){
    temp_L1 = lapply(as.character(data[[column]]), function(x) sapply(3:nchar(x), function(i) substr(x, i-2, i)))
    temp_L1_length = max(lengths(temp_L1))
    temp_L1 = lapply(temp_L1, function(x)
        sapply(x, function(y){
            num_a = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "a", text = y, ignore.case = TRUE))
            num_a = sum(num_a > 0)  #length of positive match
            num_b = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "b", text = y, ignore.case = TRUE))
            num_b = sum(num_b > 0)
            num_c = unlist(gregexpr(pattern = "c", text = y, ignore.case = TRUE))
            num_c = sum(num_c > 0)
            num_a * 1 + num_b * 3 + num_c * 7
        })
    )
    temp_L1 = setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(temp_L1, function(a)
        a[1:temp_L1_length]))), nm = paste0(column,"_",1:temp_L1_length))
    return(temp_L1)
}

#USING ON NEW DATA
cbind(df, do.call(cbind, lapply(colnames(df)[-1], function(x) foo(data = df, column = x))))
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your update. so sorry but I'm still experiencing a problem. I'm finding that this code generates 3 copies of every new column i.e. L1_1, L1_1, L1_1. I've tested this with different columns and can't quite figure out why this is happening. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `tidyverse` verbs

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
      mutate(L2=L1) %>%              # copies L1
      nest(L2) %>%                   # nest L1
      mutate(data=map(data,~sapply(1:(nchar(.x)-2), function(y) substr(.x, y, y+2)))) %>%       # makes triplets
      unnest(data) %>%        # unnest triplets
      group_by(ID) %>%        # perform next operations group wise
      mutate(rn=letters[row_number()]) %>%        # make future column names
      spread(rn,data)         # spread long format into wide format (columns)

     ID     L1     a     b     c     d
1     1 abbbcc   abb   bbb   bbc   bcc
2     2 aabacd   aab   aba   bac   acd
3     3  abbda   abb   bbd   bda  <NA>
4     4   bbad   bba   bad  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: thanks so much! unfortunately I'm implementing this in Spotfire and am not able to use other libraries.

Comment: No problem. Looks like the base R solution should work for you